# Como pegar JSON de uma url externa

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Estou tentando pegar um *JSON* de uma pagina externa, estou usando o `dataType=jsonp`, mas só que a url, me retorna um *JSON* e o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

O *JSON* me retorna o seguinte token:

```
{"token":"WLAR-i0ad819840000014fcceb5726da5fd20a"}
```

e eu o meu código esta assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                                                               
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a requisição não retorna a chamada de um método e você quer interpretar a resposta como JSONP, você deve simplesmente mudar

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Para:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

**EDIT**

Você ainda pode "burlar" essas exceções de CrossDomain usando um CORS proxy, como o http://cors.io/ ou o http://crossorigin.me/

O código ficaria algo como:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://cors.io/?u=http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                                                               
});
```

Ou...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://crossorigin.me/http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                                                               
});
```

Comment: para acessar de domínios diferentes eu não posso usar o  `dataType: 'json'` , os navegadores não permitem esse tipo de requisição

Comment: O que você pode fazer para acessar domínios diferentes assim é usar um CORS proxy, como http://cors.io/ ou http://crossorigin.me/

Comment: Deixar o `dataType` como `'jsonp'` nesse caso é errado, o jQuery vai esperar a chamada de uma função

Comment: mas ao usar o `'json'`ele retorna o seguinte erro:

`crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests) Type: Boolean If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added: 1.5)`

Comment: E se você utiliza-se o `json` habilitando `crossDomain` como true? Falei isso quando editei a minha resposta acima. Se ajudar leve em consideração para tirar esse -1 da resposta que dei.

Comment: Faça com o exemplo que @RafaelTelles adicionou, testei aqui e funcionou com o CORS.IO

Comment: Se usarmos o cors ou o crossorigin, ele retorna sucesso, mas o dados que vem como sucesso é uma mensagem de erro `"{"error":{"errors":["incorrect_userid"],"localizedErrorMessages":["incorrect_userid"],"firstError":"incorrect_userid"}}`

Comment: @RafaelCabral, você não está passando dados junto com a requisição

Comment: A requisição está sendo feita com sucesso, se há mais algum problema, sugiro que faça outra pergunta, para não poluir esta

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que observei no seu código existe uma vírgula (`,`) logo após o fechamento do `success` na sua chamada AJAX, no código abaixo retirei a vírgula, observe:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); }
});
```

O que você poderia fazer para deixar a vírgula é chamar outra função ou atributo do jQuery AJAX, como, por exemplo, `error`, `complete`, segue o exemplo mostrando que retornou uma mensagem de erro logo após a declaração da função `sucess`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() {    
        console.log('Success!'); 
    }, error: function(e){
         alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
    }
});
```

Repare que após fechar a função `error` não coloquei uma vírgula no final da função, isso serve para declarações dos de mais atributos ou funções que possam a vir por último na declaração do AJAX.

**EDIT**

Baseado no comentário do Sergio na minha resposta quanto que as vírgulas não influenciam resolvi colocar o código no JSFiddle e testar, realmente o problema persistiu, então fiz o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); }

});
```

Repare que retirei o `jsonp` e coloquei no lugar o `json` apenas, porém agora está retornando este erro falando que o acesso externo não é permitido:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

**EDIT**

Para habilitar que o AJAX acesse externamente, declare isso em seu AJAX:

```
 crossDomain: true,
```

Documentação:

> crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)
>   Type: Boolean
>   If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added: 1.5)

**EDIT**

Exemplo como ficaria sua chamada AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.revistadostribunais.com.br/maf/api/v1/authenticate.json?sp=ESDEVA-1', 
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); }                                                                                                                               
});
```

Comment: Ter ou não virgula esquecida não faz diferença: http://jsfiddle.net/8jucf87s/

Comment: Exatamente que o Sergio disse, a virgula não faz diferença :|

Comment: os "dois pontos"  retornados como erro vem do  `{"token":"WLAR-i0ad819840000014fcceb5726da5fd20a"}`

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio pelo seu comentário, editei o post. Experimente agora trocando o `jsonp` por `json`, acredito que vai retornar agora outro problema quanto acesso externo. Se encontrar a solução para este problema editarei o post novamente.

Comment: Sim, mudar pra `JSON` não é possível, os navegadores não permitem esse tipo de requisição

Comment: Experimente declarar isso na sua chamada AJAX: `crossDomain: true,`

Comment: Qual foi o resultado? O que fez para funcionar?

Comment: Por enquanto eu ainda não consegui fazer funcionar com jquery com nenhuma das opções, o que eu consegui foi pegar com PHP, mas minha aplicação é C#, então não serviu de muita coisa, com C# tbm ainda não consegui pegar... mas isso é questão pra outro topico...

Comment: vou buscar mais na internet, e depois posto minha solução aqui!